# Can a vector field pass through an area and have zero flux?

Tags: vector-fields

Consider $x^3$ for example, at $x=0$ , the tangent line is also intersects the function. The tangent line passes through to the other side at the same point it is tangent to the function.

It got me wondering, why can't a vector field enter a closed surface (creating a negative flux) and get out tangent to the surface, with zero flux, leaving total of negative flux in contradiction to gauss's law.

[image]

Comment: Anyone knows what tags can I add?

Comment: Can you sketch the vector field you have in mind?

Comment: Which "Gauss's Law" did you have in mind? There's one related to electromagnetism. If you omit all physical requirements, and also all kinds of discontinuities and/or singularities inside the closed surface, you can do a lot of things to your vector field.

Comment: @user7530 Added. Tried to draw all the lines tangent to the surface at the exit points, same as $x^3$

Comment: @DavidK All I know is that the flux through a closed surface should be zero, when there are no sources inside the surface, zero divergence.

Comment: The divergence theorem applies to a complete vector field, not just a few streamlines. If you do manage to draw a complete field that appears to have non-zero net flux, look for where you have non-zero divergence.

Answer (score 1):

The total flux is only zero when the vector field is divergence-free.

If your example vector field (a) is divergence-free and (b) can be extended to complete the diagram without introducing a region of positive flux, then indeed you would have a counter-example to Stokes's theorem. But you can prove that constructing such an example is impossible.

If your vector field (call it $v$) is divergence-free, then its 90-degree-counterclockwise rotation $v^{\perp}$ is curl-free, and so is the gradient of some function,
$$v^{\perp} = \nabla f.$$
Let's think about what $f$ must look like to match your picture. We can set $f$, WLOG, to equal zero at the middle-left point on the boundary (where your first streamline enters the region). Let's imagine what happens to $f$ as we move clockwise around the boundary.

In the top-left part of your diagram, $f$ increases. This is because $v^{\perp} = \nabla f$ points to the upper-right, and is aligned with the direction of travel.

In the region where $v$ leaves the region parallel to the boundary, $v^{\perp}$ leaves perpendicular to the boundary. Therefore $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the boundary and $f$ is constant along that part of the boundary.

So we have that $f$ started at $0$ in the middle-left, increased to some positive value as we moved towards the top of the region, and then didn't change as we moved along the right part of the boundary. Now by the time we finish winding around the boundary, and return to our starting point, $f$ must decrease back to zero. This means that $\nabla f$ must point to the right along the bottom portion of the boundary, and so $v$ must point down. In other words, any divergence-free completion of your vector field must have streamlines that exit through the bottom of the boundary, providing the positive flux required by Stokes's theorem.

Comment: Do we have to complete the vector field? If I only have a thin stream of water, does it's flux through a closed surface can be non zero?

Comment: @EB97 You need a sufficiently-smooth divergence-free field for Stokes's theorem to imply that the flux is zero.

If you model a stream of water as a velocity field supported within a thin volumetric tube, that is divergence-free and vanishes as you approach the boundary (no-slip conditions), then yes, the flux is zero.

Comment: In any case, I did not assume anywhere above that $v$ doesn't vanish in some places. It can vanish, but as I argued above, if it's divergence-free, there must be a region along the bottom boundary where $v$ passes downwards over the boundary and has positive flux.

Comment: The divergence-free condition is very important and may be stronger than you intuitively think. If you draw some arbitrary streamlines, they will *not* in general correspond to a divergence-free vector field. And of course, arbitrary vector fields that are not divergence-free can have arbitrary net flux.